# CLion setting up Qt and getting numerous errors stating 'undefined reference to '_imp___ZN

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, clion

I am getting several undefined reference errors with using Qt. I am using MinGW as my compiler and I am using Qt version 5.15.2.

This is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(jerseytraffic)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 5)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core Gui Widgets)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "A:\\CppProjects\\CppLibraries\\Qt5\\5.15.2\\mingw81_64\\lib\\cmake\\")

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
```

This is main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Hello World";
    return QCoreApplication::exec();
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
CMakeFiles\jerseytraffic.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplicationC1ERiPPci'
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK14QMessageLogger5debugEv'
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6QDebugD1Ev'
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv'
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplicationD1Ev'
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6QDebugD1Ev'
A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplicationD1Ev'
CMakeFiles\jerseytraffic.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN7QString8fromUtf8EPKci':
A:/CppProjects/CppLibraries/Qt5/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h:706: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QString15fromUtf8_helperEPKci'
CMakeFiles\jerseytraffic.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN6QDebug10maybeSpaceEv':
A:/CppProjects/CppLibraries/Qt5/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore/qdebug.h:129: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11QTextStreamlsEc'
CMakeFiles\jerseytraffic.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN6QDebuglsEPKc':
A:/CppProjects/CppLibraries/Qt5/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore/qdebug.h:159: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11QTextStreamlsERK7QString'
CMakeFiles\jerseytraffic.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData':
A:/CppProjects/CppLibraries/Qt5/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:239: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_jj'
```

This is what I get in the CMake output when it reloads:

```
"A:\ProgramFiles\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" A:\CppProjects\jerseytraffic
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: A:/CppProjects/jerseytraffic/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

One thing I have tried is modifying the cmake file by adding this around the add_executable line, but it did not make any changes:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core)
```

Some other things that I have attempted include:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug -G \"MinGW Makefiles\"")
```

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe")
```

```
option(G "MinGW Makefiles")
```

- I added this CMake option in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake > Debug > CMake options: `-G "MinGW Makefiles" %*`

However, none of these seemed to fix the error.

Comment: The compiler you use to compile your program is not mingw/gcc but msvc - otherwise the file extension of your object files would be .o and not .obj. Make sure to select the correct compiler when calling cmake (e.g. specifiy it via '-G MinGW Makefiles')

Comment: I'm using mingw as my compiler for this. Is there a particular thing you see in my code that sets the compiler to msvc?

Comment: I already told you why I know that the msvc compiler is picked up: otherwise the file extension of your object files would be .o and not .obj

Comment: Can I do: set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe") or option(G "MinGW Makefiles")?

Comment: You have to pass the proper generator to cmake with '-G...' like O said in my first comment.

Comment: Am I supposed to add this CMake option: `-G "MinGW Makefiles" %*` in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake > Debug > CMake options?